# Why using async/await to a function takes longer time then calling that same function directly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a function which I need to run in background because it freezes the UI until it completes. I tried to use Async/Await which lets me use the UI no matter the function completes running or not, but I noticed it is much slower. Why using async/await to a function takes longer time then calling that same function directly ? Is there any other alternative ?

```
private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Math4OfficeRibbon.CallFunction();
   MessageBox.Show("Task Finished");
}

public async void CallFunction()
{
   await Task.Run(() => AwaitedFunction());
}

public static void AwaitedFunction()
{
   // Do Something
   // Takes longer time this way
}
```

Comment: **Much** slower? It could be tiny bit slower because under the hood it creates statemachines and other stuff, however I doubt it can be much slower.

Comment: "it is much slower"... is the invocation of the method slower, or the running of its code?

Comment: @Stan  It is much much slower.. atleast 20 times slower than normal function call.

Comment: @spender running time of the awaited function code is longer than normal function call.

Comment: Could it be that you've starved your threadpool by queueing more work that it has cleared? If you throw lots of jobs into the threadpool, there is latency before it spins up extra thread to deal with the work... Otherwise... Perhaps you pressed the button more than once?

Comment: Is this a wpf app? If so why not just change your method signature for btnClick? `private async void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` ? Also how are you measuring the time difference? You should not have the debugger attached when measuring.

Comment: What's the *nature* of `AwaitedFunction`? Have you had to modify it extensively to get to this point by e.g. adding lots of `Invoke` calls to it?

Comment: @spender naah.. single button click performs this task, and there are no other awaited function on this button press.

Comment: @Igor It is an VSTO application. I am measuring the running time by stopwatch..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't get u !!

Comment: @AnkurGupta Does the called method interact a lot with the UI?

Comment: @AnkurGupta - is this function actually trying to interact with lots of UI elements (or with one UI element repeatedly)? If so it's just going to spend lots of its time trying to get back *onto* the UI thread to do its work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, It searches some specific texts written in the Word document from top to down by finding the ranges. But there is no interaction with the UI as I find the TextRange at first and use that textRange to search for the texts needed to be found.

Comment: The `TextRange` is almost certainly a COM component bound to the UI thread. You're going to be doing lots of marshalling to get back onto the UI thread for most method calls. All of this is entirely non-obvious from the code you've chosen to show us in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find out why it's much slower you can track events down in visual studio by using `Console.WriteLine($"{event name} {DateTime.Now}")`
And then seeing where it takes the most time in output window.
However about the alternatives, I suggest you use BackgroundWorker to run your tasks.
***note that you need to invoke controls in order to make changes to the ui  through the backgroundWorker***

```
BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_worker.DoWork+=(o,args)=>
{
//your code here.
}
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

You also have RunWorkerCompleted event which you can use to do things after your task is done running.
Backgroundworker also has the `IsBusy` property which you can use along with a while loop to keep the thread waiting for its completion without freezing the UI by doing :

```
While(_worker.IsBusy)
{
Application.DoEvents();
}
```

In order to invoke to do things on the ui thread you need to do the following within BackgroundWorker:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> 
{
//ui action here for example:
MessageBox.show("test")
}));
```

However in order to find out why your asynchronous operation takes alot of time you have to trace it using the console because you have all the code and you know what you're doing.

Comment: Very true, but MSDN highly discourages use of `BackgroundWorker` in new code: "The async-based approach to asynchronous programming is preferable to existing approaches in almost every case. In particular, this approach is better than BackgroundWorker for IO-bound operations because the code is simpler and you don't have to guard against race conditions. In combination with Task.Run, async programming is better than BackgroundWorker for CPU-bound operations because async programming separates the coordination details of running your code from the work that Task.Run transfers to the threadpool"

Comment: true, though i just tried to point to an alternative as was requested by the OP.  :)